# Release certificate with google maps V2 on google play

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have Implemented Google maps V2 Successfully.I have made debug as described by  [Google Map Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start). Now its time to release my app with Google Maps on Google Play.For it i have to make  release certificate  of Google maps.And i am not understanding first step of  [release certificate fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) .

1. From Where to download Keystore file? it is From api console google
2. Where is  release certificate keystore file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the keystore you create yourself for signing your applications. You don't download it from anywhere. You should not give it to anyone, not even Google.

See http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode for more information.

Comment: i have keystroke file which is used when ever i export apk for google play. i think i have to keep debug certificate in android manifest .and use stored keystroke file ( used when ever i export any apk for google play) while exporting my this google map apk

Answer (score -1):

Me too faced the same problem during releasing my app to google Play, when I used Google Maps V2 in my app. After succeeding the issue, I wrote a blog post regarding this you can have a [look](http://smdaudhilbe.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/how-to-create-release-keystore-digitally-sign-publish-android-app-to-google-play-android-market/).

As everyone requested, I would say the answer in following steps
1) Sign up your app using eclipse adt
2) Note down the SHA1 finger print which will be displayed at console of your eclipse adt
3) Again go to google console and get API_KEY for your app by using above got SHA1 fingerprint
4) Replace the old API_KEY with the new API_KEY on to manifest.xml of your app
5) Again sign up your app. Your app is ready to be published. But keep in mind that once you published your app to google market, you should be able to release updates to your app by signing **.apk** using the keystore which you used earlier for release.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: I described how to actually sign an app before publishing to market when the app deals with Google Maps V2..@Bhusan thanks for your info

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.